# Filtering Custom Instance Id (AMI) to use in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have customized an image using packer and I can launch an instance from that Image Id. If I use that Image Id as-is then I can deploy a small stack. No problems there. But I am constantly spinning new Images based on feedback and so new images have new Image Ids. Is there a way that I can filter new Image Ids and use the latest one that I built using Packer in my cloudformation stack? I had a look at other posts but my question is slightly diff in that I am building the images which show up in AMIs when I filter using 'owned by me' and not from marketplace. Any suggestion/help will be appreciated.

```
WIN-APP-01
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties: 
    AvailabilityZone: !Ref WinAvailabilityZone
    EbsOptimized: True
    IamInstanceProfile: !Ref WinInstanceProfile
    ImageId: ???
    InstanceType: T2.Micro
    UserData: 
      'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash
        yum install -y httpd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [CloudFormation Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) powered by an AWS Lambda function that would:

- Call `DescribeImages()` with `owner=self`
- Filter down to the images of interest (eg by something in the description)
- Sort by date
- Return the most recent AMI

This is similar to: [Walkthrough: Looking Up Amazon Machine Image IDs - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html)

That walkthrough was made to help people use the latest Windows or Amazon Linux AMIs. This method has now been superseded by [using the Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) to retrieve an AMI. However, this method only uses pre-coded AMIs provided by AWS.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the limitation of Parameter store that it only uses pre-coded AMIs provided by AWS. I thought I could use it for any image.